# Restful application with update entity

Tags: spring, rest

Given a controller which will create/update/delete/query for `User`:

```
Get     /users      query the list
Post    /users      add a new user

Get     /users/1    query a single record
Delete  /users/1    delete a single record
Put     /users/1    update a single record
```

Note the last `Put` method to action `/users/1` which means the user of identify `1` should be updated with the data in the request.

However suppose the user with identify 1 have the following properties(partially):

```
{username:uname,location:sg}
```

Now given the following requests:

```
PUT /user/1
    username=hg

PUT /user/1
    username=hg&location=
```

We should set the `username` to `hg`, but how do we handle the `location`? Should it be set null or left as it is in the database?

Generally we may use the Data binding like spring mvc in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{userId}",method="PUT")
public String update(@PathVariable String userId, User user){
    //merge the model, suppose the `user` contains all the properties of the user
    user = entityManager.merge(user);
    entityManager.persist(user);
    return "user/show"
}
```

In this case, once the two example requests are executed, the location will set to null in the database, which may or not what the client want.

Normally, we should use the `Patch` to update the partial properties of the resource, however not all the framework support that method.

And what's more, even the `Patch` method is supported like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{userId}",method="PATCH")
public String updatePartial(@PathVariable String userId, User user){
    //just set the properties no null
    User userInDB=entityManager.find(userId);
    //iterator all the properties, set the property which is not null or empty to the userInDB
    entityManager.persist(userInDB);
    return "user/show"
}
```

As shown, we have to check the properties of the model, it would be tedious once the model have some deep nested beans.

What's your general practice when handling this kind of situation?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use mentioned `PATCH` method if partial (in the meaning of fields) request is being sent. Then, all the fields that are present in the request should be modified - set to null value e.g.

When it comes to `PUT` you should not accept partial requests - since this is not compatible with the standards. When a request is syntactically correct you should modify all the fields unless DB constraints prevents you to do so. So if a particular user can (in terms of the system) set location to null value, he/she should be allowed to do so. If it's not possible you should raise bad request exception and return 400 status code along with the message.

Comment: @hguser, if my answer helped you, please upvote and accept it.